# Archer's Sunder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

The [Archer's Trick shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/archer/) allows them to sunder. However the rules for damaging objects states "Objects take half damage from ranged weapons (unless the weapon is a siege engine or something similar)."

Does this mean that an archer trying to sunder will always do 1/2 damage then have to try to bypass hardness? That seems like it would lead to really underwhelming damage numbers.

Comment: Well, when you think about it realistically, an arrow is not going to do much damage to a stone, no matter how hard you hit it. The arrow would sustain more damage than the object would.

Comment: Also depends a lot on what you're sundering - wands or potions or scrolls might be more vulnerable than weapons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is weak...**

...but it is better than the alternative.  You correctly noted that objects take half damage from non-siege ranged weapons, but if you look a bit earlier in the section "Smashing an object" (emphasis mine):

> Smashing a weapon or shield *with a slashing or bludgeoning weapon* is
> accomplished with the sunder combat maneuver (see Chapter 8).
> Smashing an object is like sundering a weapon or shield, except that
> your combat maneuver check is opposed by the object's AC.  *Generally,
> you can smash an object only with a slashing or bludgeoning weapon.*

The trick allows an archer to attempt something that they would normally be completely unable to attempt.  Let's examine an example:  5th level fighter (archer) using a composite long bow +1 (+3 STR bonus) with the feats Point Blank Shot, Deadly Aim and (Weapon focus +) Weapon Specialisation attacking a target within 30'.  Damage will be d8+12, for a result range of 13-20.  Against a hafted weapon or projectile weapon with hardness 5 and 5 hp, there's a good chance of giving it the broken condition and the possibility of destroying it.  However, against any target with hardness 10 (eg all metal weapons) there is no chance of inflicting any damage.

Personally, I am not a fan of sundering weapons as a tactic, but for an archer who concentrates on neutralising enemy archers by targeting their weapons, this has the potential to be effective.

Comment: It may be worth noting that giving an object the Damaged condition, notably a weapon, generally disables its magic as well as giving the user a penalty. Attempting to cripple but not destroy weapons in this way can be an effective tactic.

Comment: The problem i see with that is that against magic weapons it becomes a non-option. Take a lv 12, with a +3 composite longbow with flaming frost. 1d8+5 str+3enhancement+8 deadly aim+2d6 elemental. for an average shot damage of 27.5 lets be generous and say this average is 30 per shot.... A +3 weapon has a potential hardness of 16. You do 0 damage. A wooden weapon has 11. you do 4 of 30+ hp..  4/16 to apply broken condition. this is also assuming its not a special material. It just doesnt seem like an option in a lot of cases. or able to  compare to 20ft reach melee sunder. for 10 extra feet?

Comment: @Erudaki as I said in the first line, yes, it's weak.  If I chose to use this tactic at all as a level 12 archer, I would use it to target a minion's projectile weapons (which are more likely to be +1 than +3 weapons).  You're also missing a vital (literally) few points of damage in your estimate for a 12th level archer:  +2 for Expert Archer, +1 for Point Blank Shot, +4 for greater weapon specialisation, +2d8 for Improved Vital Strike.  That puts average shot damage up to 43.5 - after 2 attacks even a +3 bow is broken.